# Не отображается статус перенаправления и заголовок перенаправления

Tags: http, сеть, golang, http-status-code-301, http-заголовки

Мой парсер проходится по всем url адресам и файлам `.php` которые только может найти. Когда парсер посылает запрос на `http://www.newtender.ru/redirect.php?url=http://example.com` он должен понимать что это перенаправление, а понимать он должен по статус коду и заголовку `Location`, но почему то когда парсер посылает запрос на `http://www.newtender.ru/redirect.php?url=http://example.com` сервер возвращает статус код `200`, без заголовка `Location`, почему так? когда сервер вернуть заголовок `Location` и статус код 301 свидетельствующий о том что сервер перенаправил мой запрос. В браузере Chrome всё отлично работает, мониторинг через вкладку **Network**, пример ответа:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 15:54:41 GMT
location: http://example.com
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny16
```

Парсер получает вот такой ответ:

```
Server:[nginx]
Date:[Tue, 26 Feb 2019 15:57:38 GMT]
Content-Type:[text/html; charset=UTF-8]
Vary:[Accept-Encoding]
X-Powered-By:[PHP/5.6.40]
Connection:[keep-alive]
Keep-Alive:[timeout=20]
```

В чем проблема и как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Не может быть проблема в том, что у вас `location` вместо стандартного `Location`?

Comment: @Ainar-G не в этом проблема, я уже проверял, заголовки выдает одни и те же без Location в как бы он не был формате. И статус код 200, не может быть при редиректе статус код 200 априори.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена отключением перенаправления в `http.Client{}`, функцией `CheckRedirect`.

```
hc := &http.Client{
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        },
}
```